# Hudson/Jenkins Mylyn Builds Connector gets "Unexpected Error: Forbidden"

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

My situation:

- Eclipse 4.19 (Windows)
- Jenkins 2.332.2 (Linux)
- No firewalls between.

I installed via Eclipse Marketplace "Hudson/Jenkins Mylyn Builds Connector" (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector)

Via "Window - Show View - Other" I open the "Builds" View.

I follow the wizard and enter the appropriate Values.
After pushing "Validate" I receive
"Server validation failed: Unexpected Error: Forbidden"

User and password are OK - login via Webinterface is possible.

As alternative I tried "Anonymous" after enabling this in Jenkins.

Then I receive:

"Server validation failed: Unexpected Error during invocation of operation"

What am I doing wrong?
Where can I find a log?